When working with real life data, how do you handle many missing/NAs in columns for modelling?
I'm kind of a newbie in this regard and having trouble understanding or how to deal with it.
I work with a lot of patient data and this data comes from nurses/doctors about how patients are treated. I am currently using a logistic model (binary) and it works okay with a few columns. Sometimes in certain situations, some sections of data are not available i.e. age or gender which is fine for me because that doesn't happen a lot and I can remove these observations however as you add more columns, there is more chance of data having NA's/being missing. I know when there are not many missing data points, it is okay to remove them and regard them as anomalies however when you have a large dataset, this naturally increases.
What do I do in this regard?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How do you deal with large amounts of missing data when you are trying to incorporate many columns when each column has a different number of missing data/NAs making high amounts of incomplete observations?

Welcome to Cross Validated! This page outlines a well respected approach, multiple imputation of the missing data. The online Flexible imputation of missing data explains in detail. Also see Chapter 3 of Frank Harrell’s Regression Modeling Strategies.

If the page linked as a duplicate and the items linked in my comment don't answer your question, please edit the question to make it more specific to what is still unclear.
